# Постраничная навигация и большое количество параметров

Tags: php, html, form

На странице поиска имеется большое количество форм  (30 текстовых полей, 5 выпадающих списков и текстареа). Данные отправляются на страницу site.ru/person/search и там же выводится результат поиска, по 15 записей. **Вопрос**: как организовать по страничную навигацию? Где сохранять параметры поиска? Правильно ли все данные передавать методом GET?

Comment: Пока очень пространный вопрос. В чем вы видите проблему?

Answer (score 3):

Сама по себе передача через GET 36 параметров никаких особых проблем не представляет. Главное, учтите, что очень длинные урлы могут привести к ошибке 400.

Если вы не хотите пугать пользователя, то я навскидку вижу три варианта.

1. Положить всё в `$_SESSION`, через `$_GET` передавать только старницы. Минус один: ссылкой на результат поиска нельзя поделиться (и сохранить ее).
2. Всё как в п.п. 1, только в `COOKIES`. Минус тот же.
3. Подключить key-value хранилище (`redis`, например), и хранить результаты поиска в `JSON`, передавая через `$_GET` ключ. Если хостинг ограничивает, можно и табличку в `Mysql` сделать, но это совсем не то, для чего предназначены реляционные СУБД.

Comment: Можно если запрос сохранять в б.д. а в сылке писать его хэш, по которому этот запрос доступен.

Comment: Это как раз третий вариант